# AngularJS + jasmine+karma: service response mocking in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

i'm struggling with testing angular controller method which have call to service in it, example:

```
function methodInController() {
service.callToService()
.success(function(){})
.error(function(){});
}
```

How should i mock service.callToService()? Because now karma reading controller and throwing error that TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object <...> near .error(function(){}).

Comment: How are you calling `methodInController` ? It looks private.

Comment: No, it's not, it's just example. This method is called by karma as well, passes .success branch, and throws error on .error branch.

Answer (score 0):

Create a promise using `$q` and return that.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
spyOn(service, 'callToService').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
deferred.resolve({fake: 'data'});
$scope.$digest();

expect(service.callToService).toHaveBeenCalledWith({some: 'arguments'});
expect(controller.myCuccessHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(controller.myErrorHandler).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

etc.
Repeat and adjust for your failure case and whatever else you want to test.

Comment: Will try it tommorow, will be clear. 
Now im using this .and.returnValue({success: function(){}});

Comment: That can work too, but when you're testing a lot of these functions it's much easier to just use $q like angular does, and also using $q will more closely resemble the behaviour of your app (won't do anything until the next digest cycle for example). You'll end up typing that out a lot so you'll probably make a function to create that mock object, but if you're making such a function... might as well just use $q :P

Comment: Nope, my approach dont working. Karma says that .error is undefined and cant evaluate.

Comment: I presumed you were just showing me part of your fake object. This doesn't contain an error function: `{success: function(){}}` The approach does work, you just haven't filled it in fully. Another reason in favor of $q